# Reduce the array type to a specific one? ['a','b'] of type ['a','b'] instead of string[]

Tags: typescript

I have an array of strings, I need to reduce it to type of an array with specific values
That is, ['a', 'b'] of type string[] must be of type ['a','b']
You can, of course, write "['a','b'] as ['a','b']" manually, but this is not very convenient

```
export function myFunction<T extends string[]>(
  required: T
): Record<T[number], any> {}
```

I need this function to return object with entries that "required" array contains, so if I call myFunction(['a','b','c']), compiler and IDE should know that object that is returned contains only a, b and c keys
Now it works when I call it like myFunction(['a','b','c'] as ['a','b','c']), but I don't want to explicitly specify the type
How do I cast type of "required" variable automatically?

Comment: See [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NaZ0om) with a `const` type param modifier work for you? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that helped! Thx

Comment: Node.js is not related to this question. The question is about TypeScript and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an array literal like `["a", "b", "c"]` is inferred to have a `string[]` type.  But if the array literal is in a so-called "`const` context", it will be inferred as a [`readonly` tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types): `readonly ["a", "b", "c"]`.  This is close to what you want: you didn't ask for `readonly`, but unless you intend to modify the array it shouldn't matter much, and there's not much point in modifying the contents of an array when each element's type is a known literal string value.  I'm going to assume you don't care about that.

One way to get a `const` context is for the person who writes the array literal to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const a = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
// const a: readonly ["a", "b", "c"]
const p = myFunction(a);
// const p: Record<"a" | "b" | "c", any>
```

But if the array literal is given directly as an argument to `myFunction()`, you can also specify a `const` context by specifying [a `const` type parameter modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to `T`:

```
declare function myFunction<const T extends readonly string[]>(
  required: T
): Record<T[number], any>;

const o = myFunction(["a", "b", "c"]);
// const o: Record<"a" | "b" | "c", any>
```

Note that in order to support a `readonly` tuple I had to change the [type parameter constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) from `string[]` to `readonly string[]`.  Otherwise the inference would fail because `readonly ["a", "b", "c"]` is not assignable to `string[]`.  Again, I assume you don't care about that, unless there's some important use case that breaks.

---

It's important to remember that if an array literal's type is inferred to be `string[]`, the more specific information about the order and literal types of the elements is thrown away and irretrievable.  You have to put the array literal in a `const` context directly somehow.  You can't add one after the fact:

```
const oops = ["a", "b", "c"]; // forgot "as const" here
// const oops: string[]

const q = myFunction(oops);
// const q: Record<string, any>
```

The type of `q` is `Record<string, any>` because `oops` is of type `string[]`.  The `const` modifier in `myFunction` can't undo that, so `q` is of type `Record<string, any>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&ssl=16&ssc=30&pln=17&pc=24#code/LAKFBMFMGMBsEMBOkAEAzArgO2gFwJYD2WKAtgJ4Bi2eRWAPNMQM64oAqKkAHrpFuGYpk8cMVjkUrRPiwBzANoBdAHwAKUCmGQAjhnzJwALg6gAlCYBKMQonD12CrBlIAjSIiUAaFPCzkVAG5QUCYsVhRCFABeMioaAmI1BQAieBSfFNcMlBToFKUzYJAAehKUMIjCKxs7ejSUlAAfXOzm3PyfPwCQkEq2eBiUVPTM7Mz8pV8hfuKyipYBkxExLAlhhrGcvILQxZQAByGKahxErDV4ItB5-sOapjqG9qzGlp2u-xVevfC2QkIByEsRG23GHQKc3KdwBQJM0lkiiUvwiOmO8TOdDUsOY11K0P2OgetnsCPknx6ICAA)